# stopping and removing thread after completing of task in .net

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have developed one window application in C# where i am creating one thread to perform one schedule event. now this application will run the whole day and it will create one thread for each execution of each event. How to remove threads from memory after task assigned to that thread is completed. I dont want to restrict number of threads creation by using thread pool and assigning it a specific count for max thread.

Comment: you need to show some source code...

Comment: What do you believe is currently still consuming memory? Do you have a list of threads somewhere?

Comment: As far as I know, once the task assigned to a Thread is completed, that thread will be terminated and we don’t need to worry about it

Comment: Thanks I will try to confirm whether it is terminated automatically or not.

Comment: Upul yes it is working. Just for your information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as a thread finishes its execution, it will no longer consume memory and it will be targeted for the garbage collector to collect it. Thus, you don't need to worry about it. However if you are using `Task`, it is a good practice to `Dispose` it when it finishes its execution. The `Task` is `IDisposable` object.

Comment: [Do I need to dispose of Tasks?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/) TL;DR *No. Don’t bother disposing of your tasks.*