# Thread Detach / Joinable Methods

Tags: c#, multithreading, join, detach

Where are the C# Thread `Detach` / `Joinable` functions?

In C++ 11 these functions are available:

```
thread::joinable()
thread::detach()
```

But they can't be found in .NET - where are they?

Comment: I don't believe there are 1:1 equivalents, as you've found. You may want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894635/stopping-and-removing-thread-after-completing-of-task-in-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would `detach` do in your mind in .NET? .NET has no automatic storage duration. This concept does not apply.

`joinable` doesn't really apply either because you can `Join` any thread, even `Thread.Current`. If you insist on C++ semantics:

```
Thread someThread = ...;
bool isJoinable = Thread.Current != someThread;
```

[`Thread` objects are subject to Garbage Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894635/stopping-and-removing-thread-after-completing-of-task-in-net) but a thread runs to completion regardless of whether the `Thread` object is still reachable. Don't worry about this.